# MultiSelectionSpinner background style not working

Tags: android, spinner

I am creating MultipleSelect Spinner and for that I have created custom class. All things are working fine.

But I want to change the style of spinner, I have tried a lot but effect don't reflect in output.

How to change background style of this custom class.

**When I change background style spinner doesn't come**

Background Style

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="#FFFF0000"/>
</shape>
```

below is my code

```
public class MultiSelectionSpinner extends Spinner implements
        OnMultiChoiceClickListener {

    public interface OnMultipleItemsSelectedListener{
        void selectedIndices(List<Integer> indices);
        void selectedStrings(List<String> strings);
    }
    private OnMultipleItemsSelectedListener listener;

    String[] _items = null;
    boolean[] mSelection = null;
    boolean[] mSelectionAtStart = null;
    String _itemsAtStart = null;

    ArrayAdapter<String> simple_adapter;

    @SuppressLint({ "ResourceAsColor", "NewApi" })
    public MultiSelectionSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);

        simple_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       // setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.spinner_bg_color));
        setBackgroundColor( getResources().getColor(R.color.red_head1)) ;
        super.setAdapter(simple_adapter);
    }

    @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "ResourceAsColor" })
    public MultiSelectionSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
       // setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.spinner_bg_color));
        setBackgroundColor( getResources().getColor(R.color.red_head1));
        simple_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        super.setAdapter(simple_adapter);
    }
```

Comment: you want to `setBackgroundColor` or something else?

Comment: I want to set setBackgroundDrawable I was just testing color is working or not!

Comment: so call it, whats the problem?

Comment: Spinner is not display come also background not come

Comment: @NiravRanpara the Spinner is display or not ?

Comment: Its display, when I add background style not display

Comment: @NiravRanpara When I add  the code `Spinner` also display but nothing is change in `Background`.

Comment: without background style its working